# What's the difference between UIViewController and ViewController?

Tags: objective-c

I just noticed after adding a new `ViewController` that it isn't a `UIViewController` like the one created by Xcode. I didn't find an answer on google so I hope one of you could explain the difference between these two to me.

**Edit**

To clarify my question:

This is the declaration of my `UIViewController`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

And this is the declaration of my `ViewController`:

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

@interface GameViewController : ViewController
```

What is the difference between these two ViewControllers?

Comment: Please show the code you are talking about

Comment: @trojanfoe There is no code that needs to be shown. One class is a subclass of `ViewController` and the other one is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

Comment: And where is `ViewController` declared?

Comment: `ViewController` must be self-defined, so code will be necessary.

Comment: Self defined?  What are you talking about?  This question cannot be answered without more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between these two ViewControllers?

Not a great deal, but it depends on the functionality defined in `ViewController`.  It's fairly common to create a *base class* that contains common functionality you want in all derived classes, and view controller classes are no exception here.

However if `ViewController` contains no real functionality, then you can simply remove it and derive `GameViewController` directly from `UIViewController`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GameViewController : UIViewController
```

<strike>I would be very surprised if Xcode generated both `ViewController` and `GameViewController` in one operation, as you imply in your question, however.  If it did, then that's new to me and I cannot see why it did it.</strike>

Comment: No I ment that Xcode created the `UIViewController`. I created the `GameViewController`

Comment: @Dalibor OK, so it's still not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Ok I was confused and didn't realize that my `GameViewController` is a subclass of my `ViewController`. I thought that `ViewController` is a class provided by Apple.

Comment: @Dalibor Ah OK.  I understand.

Answer (score 2):

`UIViewController` provides infrastructure of the view, and when you make your own ViewController it is inherited from `UIViewController`. Just to be clear: you do not modify UIViewController, you subclass it, and then modify by your own.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question at all, except the literal ``UIViewController``. Consider deleting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

UIViewController is a class provided by Apple. In order to perform UI customization for your app, you usually create subclasses of UIViewController.
ViewController is an example subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: I was wondering if OP meant the default template subclass. No code yet to verify, though.

Comment: So if `ViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` and you usually create a subclass of `UIViewController` why is there a `ViewController` at all? Does it something that `UIViewController` can't?

Comment: It's not that UIViewController can't, it just that it doesn't. UIViewController gives you an empty view, and you probably need some buttons, images, views etc. in it, to make the UI you need for your app.

Comment: ViewController is there to make it easier to quickly create a simple app and to give people new to iOS programming an easier start in their project.

Comment: Can someone please show the declaration of this `ViewController`?

Answer (score 2):

A View Controller is a concept, is what manages a part of your user interface and interaction.

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/):

> View controllers are the foundation of your app’s internal structure. Every app has at least one view controller, and most apps have several. Each view controller manages a portion of your app’s user interface as well as the interactions between that interface and the underlying data. View controllers also facilitate transitions between different parts of your user interface.

An UIViewController is just the base class of this already defined "View Controller", you add a viewController as you said, but a viewController has a class associated to it, that can be a UIViewController, UITableViewController, or variations/subclasses.